# PDO Simple User Class Wont Work

Tags: php, pdo

i'm trying to create a simple user class but i can't get the data in the database i tried a lot of different code now here is the user class

```
namespace MonetizeMedia;

class User {
private $uid;
private $fields;

public function __construct() {
    $this->uid = null;
    $this->fields = array('username' => '',
                          'password' => '');
}

public function __get($field) {
    if($field == 'uid')
    {
        return $this->uid;
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->fields[$field];
    }
}

public function __set($field, $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($field, $this->fields))
    {
        $this->fields[$field] = $value;
    }
}

public function createUser() {
    try {

    $db = new \MonetizeMedia\Database;
    $bcrypt = new \MonetizeMedia\Bcrypt(15);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(":username", $username);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $bcrypt->hash($password));

    $stmt->execute();

    return "Registration Successful";

    } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

and here is the register page

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();

include 'classes/user.class.php';

if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$User->username = $username;
$User->password = $password;

if($User->createUser()) {
    echo "DONE!";
}
else
{
    echo "An error occured while creating your account. Please try later.";
    return;
}

}

?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<title>Register</title>

 </head>
 <body>

 <form method="post" action="">
 <ul>
<li>
<label for="usn">Username : </label>
<input type="text" name="username" />
</li>

<li>
<label for="passwd">Password : </label>
<input type="password" name="password" />
</li>

<li class="buttons">
<input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />
</li>

  </ul>
  </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

i'm trying to learn php and pdo so i'm not so good at the moment

Comment: For one thing, you have no `uid` field set in your form.

Comment: Create a field called `<input type="text" name="uid" />`, that should do the trick. And add a label for it.

Comment: You do know that your class has to be wrapped inside PHP tags, right? Which are not in your posted code. I.e. `<?php...?>`.

Comment: i added the uid field there is <?php ?> wrap around my code maybe did i not copy the <?php ?> but its still not working ;S

Comment: I'll edit your class code and you can copy/paste it afterwards.

Comment: robert, you need to turn on `display_errors` and set `error_reporting = E_ALL`. trying to develop code without it is insane. php should be telling you a fatal error.

Comment: @RobertHansen I might have been wrong about adding the `uid` field. Are you using that name/variable in your database by any chance?

Comment: now i add 

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
and
    if (!ini_get('display_errors')) { ini_set('display_errors', '1');}

Comment: Fred my database is very simple atm is looks like this

uid | username | password

Comment: @RobertHansen Ok, found one problem. Your `if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {` Try changing `submitted` to `register` in your `if(isset...`. Pretty sure about that. Because it's looking for the `name` => **submitted** in `<input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />`. Or, change `name="register"` to `name="submitted"`, it's your choice.

Comment: now im getting this error
Fatal error: Call to undefined method MonetizeMedia\Database::prepare() in www\work\classes\user.class.php on line 41

Comment: @RobertHansen Because of the change of `register` to `submitted`? That makes no sense. Your `if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {` is looking for `name="submitted"` while your form says `name="register"`. Do you have anything in your database that includes **register**?

Comment: when i submit the form its say this  Fatal error: Call to undefined method MonetizeMedia\Database::prepare() in www\work\classes\user.class.php on line 41
and my code is `if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {` and the register button `<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Register" />`

Comment: @RobertHansen What's `$db = new \MonetizeMedia\Database;` for, why the **backslash** in `Database`?

Comment: @RobertHansen Try changing `namespace MonetizeMedia;` to `namespace MonetizeMedia\Database;` in the top line of your class. Least that's what I could make of it, in the PHP manual at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Comment: i'm using namespaces for my classes

Comment: I'm not familiar with `namespaces`, so I thought I'd read up on it, in the PHP manual, and that's what I got out of it. Have you tried my suggestion just above?

Comment: yes now im getting this error
Fatal error: Class 'MonetizeMedia\User' not found in www\work\index.php on line 18

Comment: @RobertHansen The only thing I can see now, is that the `createUser` function is not being called. Functions only execute (far as I know) if it is called. 
**For example:** `function writeName() { echo "John Doe"; } echo "My name is ";writeName();`. **Output:** `My name is John Doe`